# Why did they say Andrei Sator at the end of film is a "future" version?

Tags: tenet

I've tried web search to understand how Andrei Sator lives after being killed in the past and found e.g.

> When "future" Sator (the one on the boat) finally gets killed
>
> <sub>[gamesradar, Tenet ending explained: your biggest questions answered](https://www.gamesradar.com/tenet-ending-explained/)</sub>

I could not recall how Andrei Sator from the future got to the boat in the past. Could somebody explain if and when it was shown in the movie clearly?

Answer (score 3):

So it happens off screen, but the implication is that Sator inverts again to travel back to the yacht, just as the rest of the characters invert to travel back to the 14th (date of the final battle and Kiev explosion).

Hope that makes sense? Although this isn't depicted in the following diagram, it really helped me wrap my mind around all the perspectives of the different characters:

https://www.reddit.com/r/tenet/comments/ii38sl/tenet_character_timeline_my_first_attempt_to_map/

Then there is also this video on inversion which I found helpful:

Comment: "the implication is that Sator inverts again to travel back to the yacht". The implications of what? Why *everybody* are sure it is future Sator on the yacht? If you are sure, please explain why it is the only explanation of something.